# Retrieving TimeInMillis in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite

Database Helper

```
 public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor res = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
            return res;
        }
```

---

what i want is  `db.rawQuery("select * From "+TABLE_NAME,null WHERE COLUMN datetimez(today));`

Comment: what is  `COL_5/datetimez(today)` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe  datetimez is the name of  Column from db, I want to retrieve my datas if column datetimez = today

Comment: My answer should work then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `today` is the variable and `COL_5` is `datetimez`.

```
Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_5+ "='" + today + "'" , null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
         {
            do {
                    // your code like get columns
                }
                 while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
```

Comment: calendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
        long date1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis();                                                         Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_5+ "='" + date1 + "'" , null);
        return res;  no result

Comment: What does date1 displaying ? Is it the date same as database, including the format

Comment: I copied  calendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
        date1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis();      inside public get cursor getalldata ()to create date1 in db helper so that i can return data where in column datetimez  = date1 or that day

Comment: tnx for the code, I change time in millis to String date, and compare the date if it is the same"using your code above"  Finally I could retrieve data with date today"